# Remove Characters from url, but exclude a word using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am creating an app that will process urls, this url will have several segments (this segments are names that can have special characters),this process will work with more than 1000000 urls.

I can not replace the special characters of each segments  in a separately way because this will make the process slow. The idea is join all the segments of the url with {-} or {0} and the process the complete url in a single call.The I will replace the {-} with /

```
{-}Lake Havasu City{-}Kingman-area{-}Lake Ha/vasu City{-}North Pointe-by-Read Homes{-}hola{*e}s!fsd3$^gdfg%
```

I have this regular expression to try to get the special character but exclude the especial word

```
(?:(?<!")\{\-\}(?!"))|[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]
```

I get the special characters with this part [^0-9a-zA-Z\s], but I can not make the expression ignore the {-}

[image]

```
var url = @"{-}Lake Havasu City{-}Kingman-area{-}Lake Ha/vasu City{-}North Pointe-by-Read Homes{-}hola{*e}s!fsd3$^gdfg%";
var newUrl = RemoveSpecialCharacters(url).Replace("{-}","/")

public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string input)
{
    Regex r = new Regex("(?:(?<!")\{0\}(?!"))|[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    return r.Replace(input, " ");
}
```

And the result have to be:

```
{-}Lake Havasu City{-}Kingman area{-}Lake Ha vasu City{-}North Pointe by Read Homes{-}hola e s fsd3 gdfg
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the question, a very nice one!

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally fixed your regex. Have a look: I added `{-!` to check if the hyphen is correctly matched outside of curly braces `{}` (many thanks go to [Regex Best Trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#csharpcode)). Regex (will be used with `IgnoreCase` option) is:

```
[^0-9a-z\s{}-]|\{(?!\-\})|(?<!\{\-)\}|((?<!\{)?)\-(?(1)(?!\}))
```

In general: I added `{`, `}` and `-` to the negated character class so that we do not check them first, then I added 3 alternatives where I could check the 3 symbols in context. The most difficult part was to check if we have a hyphen inside curly braces, and it was possible with conditional expressions and a capturing group on a look-behind... Mind-breaking :)

Here is the code:

```
var InputText = @"{-}Lake Havasu City{-}Kingman-area{-}Lake Ha/vasu City{-}North Pointe-by-Read Homes{-}hola{*e}s{-!fsd3$^gdfg%";

var MyRegex = new Regex(@"[^0-9a-z\s{}-]|\{(?!\-\})|(?<!\{\-)\}|((?<!\{)?)\-(?(1)(?!\}))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);

var clean_str = MyRegex.Replace(InputText, string.Empty);
```

Output:

```
{-}Lake Havasu City{-}Kingmanarea{-}Lake Havasu City{-}North PointebyRead Homes{-}holaesfsd3gdfg
```

[image]

Comment: Our answers achieve the same result in the 1st step: `{-}Lake Havasu City{-}Kingmanarea{-}Lake Havasu City{-}North PointebyRead Homes{-}holaesfsd3gdfg `, the only difference is that you replace with `$1`, and mine needs an empty replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
(\{-\})|([\w\s]+)|\W
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/wS0kL2/2)**

And replace your content with `\1\2`. You can see the output result in the substitution section:

[image]

Comment: When I convert it to C# dont work

var re = @"/(\{-\})|([\w\s]+)|\W/g";
var str = @"{-}Lake Havasu City{-}Kingman-area{-}Lake Ha/vasu City{-}North Pointe-by-Read Homes{-}hola{*e}s!fsd3$^gdfg%";
 var subst = @"\1\2";
var r = new Regex(re);
 var result = r.Replace(str, subst);

Comment: The error is evident: the `re` var is definitely in JavaScript, not C#.

Comment: @user3334335 you can use `$1$2` instead of `\1\2`

Answer (score 0):

This is the most near that I get, is not complete perfect but works

```
var re = @"(\{-\})|([^0-9a-zA-Z\s]+)";
var str = @"{-}Lake Havasu City{-}Kingman-area{-}Lake Ha/vasu City{-}North Pointe-by-Read Homes{-}hola{*e}s!fsd3$^gdfg%";
var subst = @"$1 ";
var r = new Regex(re, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);
var result = r.Replace(str, subst).Replace("{-} ","/");
```